Inline printing capture group content from expression
Is there a way to inline print the capture group content of a pattern match? An older posting (>5yrs ago) said grep can't do it. Is that still so?
Example. I have this file
nothing to do here
abc def ghi myword1 L=123.44 bla bla1
ijk lmn 222 anotherword  L=0.77777e-37 ttt hhh
uvw xyz tttttttt finalword L=-73 abc abc
foo bar dddd word L=lulu
just another line

I want the word (and only the word) immediately preceding ' L=' char sequence. The sequence ' L=' will occur 0 or 1 times.
Desired output :
myword1
anotherword
finalword
word

I've tried sed (that was proposed in other post) but it failed.
sed -nr 's/(\S+)\s+L=/\1/p' 

Inline is preferred as this will be part of a pipeline.
cat file | good stuff | blabla > out

EDIT / UPDATE

What does "failed" mean?

It printed the full line minus the L=.

What does "failed" mean?  What did it do or not do?

This is easy in perl or Python.  Are either available in your environment?

tip #1 : try to replace /p with /g to take all matches and not only the first

tip #2 : this patter can match all the line to by replaced by the word: .?(\S+)\s+L=.

Some versions of grep with some options specified can do it but all versions of sed or awk can do it, so just use sed or awk for portability (and usually clarity, maintainability, etc. too).

You can use GNU's grep with the -o option to output only the matched substrings and the -P option support PCRE patterns, which can include a lookahead assertion:
grep -oP '\w+(?=\s+L=)' file


And if you need to expand on the PCRE, it's perl -lne 'print $1 if /(\w+)(?=\s+L=)/' and/or all the other perlish things you can do.

If "it fails" because your sed is not GNU sed, with any POSIX (2024) sed you can try:
sed -nE 's/(.*[[:space:]]|^)([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+L=.*/\2/p'

It is the equivalent of the GNU sed:
sed -nE 's/(.*\s|^)(\S+)\s+L=.*/\2/p'


If the sequence will occur only 0 or 1 times:
(^|.*\s)(\S+)\s+L=.*

The regex matches:

.* Match the whole line
(^|\s) Assert the start of the string or match a whitespace character in group 1
(\S+) Capture 1+ non whitespace chars in group 2
\s+L= Match 1+ whitespace chars followed by L=
.* Match the rest of the line

In the replacement use capture group 2
sed -nr 's/(^|.*\s)(\S+)\s+L=.*/\2/p' file

Output
myword1
anotherword
finalword
word

See a sed demo and a regex demo to see the matches.

As an alternative you might use awk and print the column before matching a column that starts with L=
To make sure there is a column before matching L=, you can start looping the columns at the second one, and stop looping when there is a match found as there can at most 1 occurrence:
awk '{for (col=2; col<=NF; col++) if ($col ~ /^L=/) {print $(col-1); next}}' file

See an awk demo.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -nE 's/(\S+)\s+L=/\1/p' file --debug |
sed -nE '/regex\[1\]/s/.* .(.*)./\1/p'

The original regex does match but prints the entire line either side as can be seen using the debug option.
Passing the debug information on to a second invocation of sed the back reference can be identified and printed as need be.
To get the original regex to print the desired result, use:
sed -nE 's/.*\<(\S+)\s+L=.*/\1/p' file


Just as an alternative:
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    words = line.split()
    last = ''
    for w in words:
        if w[0] == 'L':
            print(last)
        last = w

Output:
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ pclip | python x1.py
myword1
anotherword
finalword
word
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$

